# Question on Apostol necessary and sufficient conditions for a field to be a gradient

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

I am reading Apostol Calculus II (2nd edition) and in section **10.15** it is stated that:

> THEOREM 10.5. NECESSARY AND SUFFICIENT CONDITIONS FOR A VECTOR FIELD TO BE A
>   GRADIENT. Let $f$ be a vector field continuous on an open connected set $S$ in $R^K$.
>
> Then the following three statements are equivalent.
>
> (a) $f$ is the gradient of some potential function in $S$.
>
> (b) The line integral off is independent of the path in $S$.
>
> (c) The line integral of $f$ is zero around every piecewise smooth closed path in S.

however later in the chapter, section **10.16** the author describes a test to determine whether a given field $f$ is a gradient:

> **10.16 Necessary conditions for a vector field to be a gradient**
>
> The first fundamental theorem can be used to determine whether or not a given vector field is a gradient on an open connected set $S$. If the line integral of $f$ is independent of the path in $S$, we simply define a scalar field $\phi$ by integrating $f$ from some fixed point to an arbitrary point $x$ in $S$ along a convenient path in $S$. Then we compute the partial derivatives of $\phi$ and compare $D_k\phi$ with $f_k$, the *k* th component of $f$. If $D_k\phi(x) =f_k(x)$ for every $x$ in $S$ and every $k$, then $f$ is a gradient on $S$ and $\phi$ is a potential. **If $D_k\phi(x) \neq f_k(x)$ for some $k$ and some $x$, then $\phi$ is *not* a gradient on $S$**.*[...]*

I don't understand how the sentence in bold can be possible, given that at the beginning of the paragraph we assumed that the line integral of $f$ was independent of the path in $S$ and for theorem 10.5 this was a necessary condition for $f$ to be a gradient.
Any clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence

> If the line integral of $f$ is independent of the path in $S$, we simply define a scalar field $\phi$ by integrating $f$ from some fixed point to an arbitrary point $x$ in $S$ along a convenient path in $S$.

could be followed by "If the line integral of $f$ is not independent of the path in $S$, then the given vector field is not a gradient on $S$."  This uses the theorem you state.  As you note, this is a straightforward obstruction to the vector field being a gradient, so Apostol doesn't explicitly write it.

However, there is more to do.  The theorem you cite requires that the vector field be continuous.  For some discontinuous vector fields, the given prescription works and this $\phi$ is well defined.  In such cases, there is more work to do to reject discontinuous vector fields -- such fields will have an obstruction in one of their derivatives.

(What's the problem with a discontinuous vector field?  Either the field is undefined at one or more points, so is not a vector field on all of $S$, or it is nondifferentiable in at least one direction at at least one point, which prevents the gradient existing at that point.  Either way, the gradient cannot exist on all of $S$, so the field cannot be a gradient on $S$.)

Comment: thanks! however, if I understood correctly, if the field is not continous it cannot be a gradient altogether, so testing for equality of $D_k\phi$ and $f_k$ still appears redundant to me, as we already know that this equality will not be true for those points where $f$ is not continous, right?

Comment: @l4teLearner : This example, http://www.math.jhu.edu/~js/Math202/example2.pdf , might be of use to you...

Comment: I see, thanks, but this is a scalar field, that is not differentiable in the origin. the matter here was non continous **vector** fields, that cannot be gradients.. I expect this example function to have a gradient everywhere but not in the origin and this gradient will be continous then in $R-(0,0)$. But then, for any open connected $S$ which does not contain the origin I still can apply theorem 10.5, while if $S$ does contain the origin the gradient is not defined in the origin, so it is not continous, hence I still see no way of using the test in section 10.6.

Comment: @l4teLearner : You seem a little turned around about what object you are holding in your hand at various steps of 10.16.  Initially, you have a vector field that may or may not be continuous and may or may not be the gradient of a scalar field.  You attempt to construct a path integral object, which is necessarily blind to point-like discontinuities, because the output of an integral is automatically continuous.  Use this path integral object to make a scalar field -- you haven't had a scalar field to talk about until this point.

Comment: @l4teLearner : The scalar filed you just got is the closest thing to a scalar field that your original vector field could be the gradient of.  Consider the initial vector field which is zero everywhere except at a finite list of points, $F$, at which it is nonzero.  The integral object is zero on every path.  The scalar field defined by the integral is constant everywhere and its gradient is zero everywhere.  So the directional derivatives of this constructed scalar field do not agree with the initial scalar field at the points of $F$.

Comment: one thing is still not clear to me. can a vector field that is non continous be a gradient? I assume no. in the last example you did the vector field was not continous in $F$, so why should I bother at all constructing a pseudo potential null everywhere which will fail to be the potential for my field in $F$ if I already know that no potential can exist where the field is not continuos ? :)

Comment: @l4teLearner : We hand the process in 10.16 a vector field.  With no additional promises.  Maybe it's continuous.  Maybe it isn't.  Maybe it's the gradient of some scalar.  Maybe it isn't.  What questions does the process in 10.16 have to answer to resolve that the vector field it was handed actually is the gradient of a scalar field.  Your question assumes *more* than we promised the procesdure in 10.16 -- it assumes that we already know something about the continuity of the vector field.  But that knowledge is *not* a hypothesis of 10.16.

Comment: thanks a lot for your patience. this clarified. I will humbly say that the procedure 10.16, at least to me, risks to bring in confusion if we don't state clearly that the cause (known or unknown) for the test to fail lies in the discontinuity of the vector field.

Comment: @l4teLearner : Apostol can easily quote 10.5: "Let $f$ be a vector field continuous on an open connected set $S$ in $R^K$."  One who intends to use 10.5 must check that hypothesis to use the conclusion.  So 10.16 checks that hypothesis so it can use the conclusion.